# Error al ejecutar archivos de java desde las variables de entorno de windows

Tags: java, windows, class, jar, windows7

No puedo usar mis archivos de java desde las variables de entorno. Uso windows 7, y al agregar la ruta a la variable de entorno PATH de windows, no me permite ejecutar los archivos de java (ni .jar ni .class).
 **Al ejecutar archivos .jar la repuesta es "Unable to access jarfile archivo.jar"**  (usando el comando: java -jar archivo.jar).
 Al tratar de ejecutar un archivo .class, la respuesta es "no se a encontrado o cargado la clase principal".
Unicamente tiene problemas con java, ya que **los otros archivos, por ejemplo los .bat, funcionan bien.**
 **Los archivos .jar funcionan perfectamente si los ejecuto desde la ruta, en lugar de intentar hacerlo por las variables de entorno.**
 Cual puede ser el error?

Comment: necesitas poner desde que carpeta lo estas corriendo en la terminal, el comando exacto y los valores de tus variables de sistema para que te podamos ayudar ya que no podemos entrar a tu computadora a revisar la configuración

Comment: Hola @victor leroz, si realmente usaste **java -jar archivo.jar"**, no va a funcionar porque le falta la apertura de las comillas, debes usar **java -jar "archivo.jar"**.

Comment: Hola @Marce Puente, gracias por el aviso. la comilla fue un error de tipeo, quise cerrar el paretesis en la consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la variable de entorno que estás usando es la variable PATH, solo sirve para ejeuctables (ficheros .exe y .bat). No sirve para ficheros "de datos". En tu caso, el ejecutable es "java.exe" (el comando java). Mientras que los ficheros .jar o .class son ficheros de "datos" de ese ejecutable "java.exe". Para windows no son ejecutables por sí mismos.

Tienes que ejecutar el comando "java -jar fichero.jar" en el directorio donde esté el fichero.jar.

Para facilitar este tipo de cosas, también suele ser relativamente habitual hacer un fichero .bat que tenga dentro una linea con "java -jar path/fichero.jar", así el directorio del .bat se puede poner en la variable PATH y el .bat es el que sabe dónde está el fichero .jar.

Se bueno.

Comment: Gracias Chuidiang!! Me sirvió muchisimo tu respeusta. Voy a crear y configurar la variable CLASSPATH y JAVA_HOME en lugar de usar PATH. Ademas fue buena idea lo de tener un archivo .bat. Gracias otra vez. Abrazo!